# Django - how to wire urls correctly? url(), include(), ImportError

Tags: django, url, structure, django-urls, importerror

I try to structure my project by putting applications under an "apps" folder, like so:

```
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── apps
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── myapp1
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── models.py
│   │   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   │   └── views.py
│   │   └── myapp2
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── models.py
│   │       ├── urls.py
│   │       └── views.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
```

And in mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^myapp1/', include('mysite.apps.myapp1.urls')),
    url(r'^mysite/apps/myapp2/', include('myapp2.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

There is something wrong with:

```
    url(r'^myapp1/', include('mysite.apps.myapp1.urls')),
    url(r'^mysite/apps/myapp2/', include('myapp2.urls')),
```

I could not wire either myapp1 or myapp2 correctly, Django gives me "ImportError...no module named myapp1..." Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a level in the relative path:

```
url(r'^mysite/apps/myapp2/', include('apps.myapp2.urls')),
```

`myapp1` looks like it should work to me.

---

A note, comparing how you're trying to include `myapp1` vs `myapp2`, it looks like you may have misunderstood the structure slightly.  The URL has nothing to do with the code layout.  This is completely valid:

```
url(r'^zimzam/allthethings/', include('apps.myapp2.urls')),
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips, Izkata. However, I tried your solution, edited sdnsite/urls.py and it still gives ImportError.

My directory structure:
http://pastebin.com/X7NnqvNv

My sdnsite/urls.py:
http://pastebin.com/nBN58BMq

Django error:
http://pastebin.com/tPTVqgua

I know there is no problem with origin/urls.py, because if I place the app at manage.py level, it would run alright.

Comment: @HowardLee Actually, the problem might be.  Take a [closer look at the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs):  Whenever they use `include()`, it's inside a plain tuple, _not_ inside a call to `url()`.  Does that work?

Comment: Problem solved! Yes are correct, myapp1 works. It's actually problem myapp1.urls.py. I had "from myapp1 import views" instead of just "import views". I should not have "from myapp1 import views" because it will look for another "myapp1" folder inside of "myapp1". I printed out python's load path and was able to trace to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this:

```
include('mysite.apps.myapp1.urls')),
```

**update**

you can try:

add a file `__init__.py` in the `mysite` dir

Comment: This is what I've tried:
If myapp1 folder is at same level as manage.py, then
    url(r'^myapp1/', include('myapp1.urls')) 
would work

Comment: @HowardLee I updated my answser,you can try it,hope it can help you